# What happens exactly when a chunk gets migrated?

Tags: mongodb

So, this is what MongoDB states:

> Independent of the secondaryThrottle setting, certain phases of the
>   chunk migration have the following replication policy:
>
> - MongoDB briefly pauses all application reads and writes to the
>     collection being migrated, on the source shard, before updating the
>     config servers with the new location for the chunk, and resumes the
>     application reads and writes after the update. The chunk move requires
>     all writes to be acknowledged by majority of the members of the
>     replica set both before and after committing the chunk move to config
>     servers.
> - When an outgoing chunk migration finishes and cleanup occurs,
>     all writes must be replicated to a majority of servers before further
>     cleanup (from other outgoing migrations) or new incoming migrations
>     can proceed.

Getting a real [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97t3O.png): the first option "All queries on documents with productId value ranging between 18684 and 27851 will be routed to shard0000" would have been correct if the upper bound was 27850 instead?

If I understood it right, when I start the migration, if I try to run a query against documents ranging between the productId values 18684-27850, MongoDB already understands that it won't have to ask to shard0003 anymore, but instead it will have to ask for those documents to the NEW destination shard and thus redirect requests to shard0000.

So, I haven't actually tryed it, but I guess what you see is that, when you run the db.collection.find(), the cmd will "freeze" and after MongoDB successfully completed the chunk migration, it will retrieve the result set, is that right?

Comment: What is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no! First config server copy all documents of moving chunk to destination server, then reading and writing is paused during time when chunk document is updated (one document, one value in that document), update is very fast process, so you don't actually notice anything. After that start cleanup at server where chunk was before.

So, you are very lucky if you managed to run collection.find() command just that moment when config server chunk collection is updated. And if you managed to do that, you probably cannot notice it or even measure that "slowness".

Comment: So, if I try to run collection.find() on a chunk that is getting migrated, the read operations get redirected automatically to the new shard, but it starts retrieving documents only AFTER the chunk has been migrated completely as a whole, right? In any case, as soon as you confirm the migration command, the config server updates immediately the shard location of where the chunk resides.

Comment: During chunk migration (during copy of documents, config server update has not happened yet) original (chunk move source) server is serving all queries. After updating config server, the new server is serving all queries. If your find is still moving documents (cursor is open) during time when config server is updated, config server is updated, but that "cleaning" part waits until your cursor is closed.

Comment: So, refered to this question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97t3O.png Both 2nd and 3rd answers are correct, right? Since, as you said, shard0003 (original server) is serving all queries during the chunk migration.

Comment: Yes. Those are right choices, at your exam... :-)